# What is Absorption Grating

Tags: quantum-information

I came across the word "absorption grating" in a review article. I googled it tried to find out what it means but couldn't. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An absorption grating is a grating, where the parallel bars are absorbing. This is in contrast to a reflection grating, where the bars would be reflecting, and a phase grating, where the bars are transmissive, but will change the phase of the incident waves. In general, physical gratings can (and usually will) introduce combinations of these three effects.

Answer (score 1):

It is a grating used in the system of X-ray differential phase contrast imaging. In front of this grating, there is a phase one, which can modulate the X-ray phase and formed a self-image at the Talbot distance. the absorption grating, generally, composed by the high aspect ratio parallel walls made of Au, used to periodically absorb X-rays. Finally，a moire fringe will emerge in a appropriate position for the two gratings. Certainly, it has many various patterns, maybe 1-D, 2-D. It can be also understand as the other way that it blocks some X-rays in special directions and then a structured X-ray would be formed.